# create empty AD-User array

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to parse through ad-groups recursive with some exceptions so i created the following code:

```
function recurse_adgroup {
    param($adgroup)
    $members_return = @{}
    #echo $adgroup
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember $adgroup | where {$_.Name-notlike"abc" -and $_.Name-notlike"cdf"}
    foreach ($member in $members){
        #echo "$($member.name)"
        if ($member.objectClass-eq'group'){
            recurse_adgroup $member.name
        }
        else{
            $members_return.Add($member)


        }
    }
   return $members_return
}
```

obviously it's not working. I think its because i need to create an array so i can add users to it.
How can i manage to do that?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Probably the best is to use the PowerShell pipeline as it is meant and drop the members you want to keep on the pipeline and eventually capture them with `$members_return = recurse_adgroup`, or even better, pass them immediately on to the next cmdlet in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember $adgroup | where {$_.Name-notlike"abc" -and $_.Name-notlike"cdf"}
    $members_return = foreach ($member in $members){
        if ($member.objectClass-eq'group'){
            recurse_adgroup $member.name
        }
        else{
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "GroupName" = $member
            }
        }
    }
   return $members_return
```

I am not sure what the if-block is supposed to do but you can try the else statement. The idea is basically to continuously add a new member to a PSCustomObject. I would suggest that you actually switch the blocks with each other. `$members_return` should return an object with all the selected users of the AD group.